# how to prints $ or \\ about regex stuff

Tags: java, regex

could you explain why `3` and `4` spit error?

in 1 and 2 cases, i made a conclusion that escaping syntax need two `\` characters like `\\` in java.

but in `3` and `4` cases, it doesn't work.

especially in `4` case, something more weird thing is when i put `\\\\`, it works.

```
  str = "$12$ \\-\\ $25$";  
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\$", ""));  //1 : 12 \-\ 25    (i get how this works)

    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^\\$", "")); //2 : 12$ \-\ $25$ (i get how this works)

    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\$$", str)); //error 3 want to print : $12$ \-\ $25

    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\", "")); // error 4 want to print : $12$ - $25$
```

Comment: Example four escapes one slash then escapes the doubles quotes (so it's an unterminated `String` literal).

Answer (score 1):

In regards to case 4, you actually need **another** `\`

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\", "")); // error 4 want to print : $12$ - $25$
```

The reason for this is java treats `\` as a special character, so it needs `\\` to get a single `\` in the string. However regex **also** uses `\` as a special character and needs `\\` to check for a single `\`, thus requiring you to escape it twice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with case 3 seems to be the replacement string (second parameter): it should be an empty string. The following code prints the expected answer `$12$ \-\ $25`.

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "$12$ \\-\\ $25$";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\$$", "")); 
    }
}
```

The case 4 is solved in the answer of @Oblivion Creations: you're missing one `\`. The following code prints the expected answer `$12$ - $25$`.

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "$12$ \\-\\ $25$";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\", "")); 
    }
}
```

Comment: gesus.. i didn't see second param 'str' i was very idiot